# Monogame - Pong game - restricting the mouse area

Tags: mouse, monogame, axes, pong

I am trying to make a simple pong game and I have two issues which I have encountered and can't seem to figure out.

For the pong game I want that the player's paddle remains within half of and lower of Y, meaning he can move the paddle within half of the 'pitch'.

I have managed to make the paddle stop at the middle, however it is dsappearing after hitting middle. Is it possible to remain within half of the Y axis without dissappearing?

And the other issue is that the player's paddle and area seem to be in the top half, not the bottom half.

Game1.cs

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Xong
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D redPaddle, bluePaddle, ball, blueBall, greyBall, bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4, elementBlue, elementRed;

        int BluePaddleX = 104;
        int BluePaddleY = 22;

        int RedPaddleX = 104;
        int RedPaddleY = 22;

        int BallX = 22;
        int BallY = 22;


        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphics.GraphicsDevice);

            redPaddle = Content.Load<Texture2D>("paddleRed.png");

            bluePaddle = Content.Load<Texture2D>("paddleBlu.png");

            blueBall = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ballBlue.png");

            greyBall = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ballGrey.png");

            elementBlue = Content.Load<Texture2D>("element_blue_square_glossy.png");

            elementRed = Content.Load<Texture2D>("element_red_square_glossy.png");


            bg1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("set1_background.png");

            bg2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("set2_background.png");

            bg3 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("set3_background.png");

            bg4 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("set4_background.png");




            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// game-specific content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();

            MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();


            int ScreenX = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width;
            int ScreenY = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height;

            int PlayerBoundaryX = (ScreenX / 2) - (BluePaddleX / 2);
            int PlayerBoundaryY = (ScreenY / 2) - (BluePaddleY / 2);

            spriteBatch.Draw(bg1, new Rectangle(0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(redPaddle, new Vector2(ScreenX, ScreenY), Color.White);

            if ((mouseState.Y < (PlayerBoundaryY / 2)) && (mouseState.Y > 0))
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(bluePaddle, new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y), Color.White);
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(bluePaddle, new Vector2(mouseState.X, PlayerBoundaryY), Color.White);
            }



            spriteBatch.Draw(greyBall, new Vector2(405, 240), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }





    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see your mouse code, but you need to monitor the mouse's movement. If they move it outside of the range you want to restrict it to, force it to the extent of the boundary. For example, if you want the max to be 100 and they move to 200, restrict the mouse position to 100.

Comment: @Frecklefoot The mouse code is this one: if ((mouseState.Y < (PlayerBoundaryY / 2)) && (mouseState.Y > 0))
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(bluePaddle, new Vector2(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y), Color.White);
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(bluePaddle, new Vector2(mouseState.X, PlayerBoundaryY), Color.White);
            }

Comment: Why is it checking for the PlayerBoundaryY divided by 2? You mentioned that the paddle appears in the top half, not the bottom half. That probably has something to do with it.

Comment: The logic is that it takes the total screen size, divides it by two and removes half of the height of the paddle, so that it takes exactly the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use Mouse.SetPosition method to push the cursor back to your desired rectangle.

Also I do recommend implementing your own "virtual FPS-style mouse" (each tick you get the relative mouse coordinates and push real mouse cursor back to the center of the window) above general Mouse class. It's often a good choice if you have some movement limitations for the cursor.

Comment: Also I guess you're creating Pong as a personal exercise, so implementing your own virtual mouse is a nice addition to it =)
Btw I came to this problem exactly as you did: I was creating Pong and needed to restrict mouse movement.